# Help with DC switch current

Tags: switches, dc, amperage

I have a DC switch rated at 2A at 36VDC, if I were running the switch at 4VDC what would be the maximum current I could safely run through it?

I'm assuming I can't simply use the wattage to calculate and I can't find a straight answer. Thanks for the help!

EDIT TO CLARIFY: It is a momentary spst on/off switch rated at 2a 36vdc being used on a high amp low voltage DC circuit.

Comment: I think you should provide more data if you want a good answer. A 'DC switch' is not clear. Is that a DC/DC power supply? Or something else? To clarify, post more data. Part number, commercial name. The best would be a link to the specs of the device.

Comment: It is a momentary spst on/off switch rated at 2a 36vdc being used on a high amp low voltage DC circuit. I'm afraid I don't have the part number to hand at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

The current rating of the switch is based on the capacity of the contacts and is not related to the voltage rating. Note that when the contacts are closed and carrying the current, the voltage across the switch is close to zero.  The voltage rating is based on the insulation and contact spacing so as to not to arc over. Thus the 2 amp rating of your switch will not increase even if you only apply 4 volts (when the switch is open).

Answer (score 0):

if you use a voltage source of 4VDC you need to measure your load resistance ie your load should not be less than 2 Ω to avoid destroying your DC switch which is rated at 2A 
this can be donne by an ohmeter across your load 
you can return to the formula to calculate your current 
i=e/r
i=4/2=2A